# Android Battery Report

Tags: battery, android-13

Is the Android OS battery breakdown not an exhaustive list of battery drain sources?

I find that it never adds up.

One time, after not restarting the phone for a month, the battery started to drain from 70% to 0% in 8 hours while I slept.

But the battery report did not report the app that cause this drain, everything was just 5% or less. And the total doesn't add up to even  25% of that drain.

Can the battery drain not detect certain sources like stuck background apps or something?

Environment:
Samsung Fold 4 Android 13

Comment: On Pixel 3a, Android 12, the Battery usage can also show the system usage, like: Screen, Wi-Fi, Phone idle, Android OS, Android System, etc. Is it not shown on your device? (Perhaps mentioning the device model might also help since manufacturers do customize their Settings menu)

Comment: Fold 4, when I check the Battery report, there's no mention of Android OS, System, WiFi.  Those could be not reported or just not incurring a significant enough consumption to be shown.